# Node.js querying MongoDB to return all matches that begin with any value from array

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb

I'm trying to query MongoDB via a Node.js application to return all matches that begin with any of the entries in the following array: ['p','q','r','s','t']

I know how to do a "begins with" for single values:

```
var value = 't';
genericCollection.find({ 'key' : new RegExp('^' + value, 'i')}).toArray(function (err, items) {
    res.send(items);
});
```

Returns:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "59788e1a1b4a3901c7fd5501",
        "key": "t-key",
        "value": "t-value",
        "lastModified": "2018-11-27T12:18:30.029Z"
    }
]
```

And I know how to do a "matches any of these values" query:

```
var values = ['p-key', 't-key'];
genericCollection.find({ 'key' : { $in : values}}).toArray(function (err, items) {
    res.send(items);
});
```

Returns:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "59788e1a1b4a3901c7fd5501",
        "key": "t-key",
        "value": "t-value",
        "lastModified": "2018-11-27T12:18:30.029Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5978ba139553e32697564d7e",
        "key": "p-key",
        "value": "p-value",
        "lastModified": "2018-11-27T12:18:55.966Z"
    }
]
```

But how can I combine the two so that I get all results from the DB that begin with *any* of those array values?

Comment: I think you need `new RegExp('^(?:' + values.join('|') + ')', 'i')`

Comment: character class will be faster than alternative (assuming you have values of size 1)

Comment: @mrzasa If they are really single characters, then certainly character classes will be more appropriate. `new RegExp('^[' + values.map(function(x) {return x.replace(/[\]^\\-]/g, '\\$&');}).join('') + ']', 'i')`. Inside character classes, `]`, `^`, ``\`` and `-` will need escaping.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks Wiktor, that's done the job. Can you post it as an answer to the question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may build an alternation based pattern from the multicharacter strings bearing in mind the necessary grouping construct (so that `^` could be applied to all of the alternatives):

```
new RegExp('^(?:' + values.join('|') + ')', 'i')
```

Note that in case the values contain special regex metacharacters you need to escape them properly:

```
new RegExp('^(?:' + values.map(function(x) {return x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');}).join('|') + ')', 'i')
```

The [regex](https://regex101.com/r/bdttJ2/2) will look like

```
^(?:t1|p2|mN)
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:t1|p2|mN)` - a non-capturing group matching any of the alternatives: `t1`, `p2`, `mN`.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a chatacter class of `[pqrst]`

```
genericCollection.find({ 'key' : new RegExp('^[pqrst]', 'i')}).toArray(function (err, items) {
    res.send(items);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works perfectly for the described problem. I would have to give Wiktor the accepted answer though, because in future I will be requiring the array to contain entries with multi-character strings